# VBA code for moving cells from one column to another based on specific cell criteria

Tags: vba, excel, range

I've seen several questions asking about moving cells from one workbook to another or one sheet to another using VBA, but I'm hoping to move information from one column to another in the same sheet based on specific criteria.

I wrote this code to move cells from column A if they contained the word "save" to column I in the same sheet:

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngA = Sheets("Jan BY").Range("A2:A1000")
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "save" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Cut
            Sheets("Jan BY").Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

But, while this macro doesn't display any errors when I run it, it also doesn't seem to do much of anything else, either. Nothing is selected, cut, or pasted. Where in the code did I go wrong?

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific, since all these answers are excellent and do exactly what I asked for in the question. When I move the contents of the cells from column A to column I, I also need to shift the entire row over. So, for example, if I have the word "save" in A1 and the number 8 in B1, both A1 and B1 need to be shifted over so that "save" is now in I1 and 8 is now in J1. I hope this makes sense? this was why I included the "cell.EntireRow.cut" line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> move cells from column A if they contained the word "save" to column I
>   in the same sheet

Your code doesn't do anything like this.

To accomplish what your requirements are, you would need something like this:

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim row As Long

    For row = 2 To 1000
        ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
        If Range("A" & row).Value Like "*save*" Then
            ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
            Range("I" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
            Range("A" & row).Value = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to shift the entire contents of row over so it starts at column `I`, just replace the relevant section of code:

```
If Range("A" & row).Value Like "*save*" Then
    ' Shift the row so it starts at column I.
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        Range("A" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Jason, your code was perfect, and it moved the column over exactly like I wanted. I completely forgot to add that I need to move the whole row over to column I if the value in column A contains "save." So instead of blanking the source I need to cut these rows and move them over 7 columns. If I can modify your code to include this change it would be perfect. Sorry for not being more specific!

Comment: @AnikaLeena - I'm not sure what you mean by _I need to move the whole row over to column I if the value in column A contains "save."_ Are you saying you want to shift the entire contents of the row over 7 cells if A contains "save"?

Comment: Yes, so if, for example, A1 contains "save" and B1 contains a number, "save" would be moved over to I1 and the number in B1 would be moved to J1.

Comment: @ Jason If I wanted to search all columns for value in stead of just searching column A, how would you implement that to the sub

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngA = Sheets("Jan BY").Range("A2:A1000")
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "save" Then
            cell.Copy cell.Offset(0, 8)
            cell.Clear
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This code scans down the column, detects the matches and performs the copy. Copying brings over the *format* as well as the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngA = Sheets("Jan BY").Range("A2:A1000")
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "save" Then
            Sheets("Jan BY").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
            Selection.Value = cell.Value
            cell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```