# Move data from cell based off of criteria from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying create a macro to move cells based off of the criteria of another cell. So basically, in the picture attached, If cell = "PS124" move contents in column "C"to column "B" and if cell = "PS588" move contents in column "C" to Column "A" and continue down all the way to the end of the empty cell.

[image]

My apologies for not typing in the code, I don't know the logic for this.

Comment: Is this just a one time thing, or a macro that will be used on a regular basis? It would be nice to know why you are doing this so that a better answer can be provided. I think you may be going down the wrong track with using a macro in the first place.

Comment: @kojow7 this would be used on a regular basis for our nursing invoices. Our data changes constantly as per invoice.

Comment: Does my answer below work for you. If not, please explain further.

Comment: @kojow7 I could do that, but i would like it to be automated with a macro. It would still manually have to delete the duplicate value in column C

Comment: It's still a bit unclear why you are doing it this way. Why are you putting the values in column C in the first place? Why do you want the values in two separate columns? Is it just so you can get a total? Or is it so you can generate an invoice? You should be able to do both of those with only column C.

Comment: @kojow7 there is a macro that is copied and pasted from another worksheet and all the values are in one column, that is why it’s all pasted in column “C”. The problem is I don’t know how to move the data to the appropriate cells.

Comment: Check the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349198/vba-code-for-moving-cells-from-one-column-to-another-based-on-specific-cell-crit - If you have trouble understanding something there, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the macro approach and instead of moving, I would keep the data in column C and then add the following formulas:

In the cell A3 I would place:

```
=if(d3 = "PS588", c3, "")
```

In the cell of B3 I would place:

```
=if(d3 = "PS124", c3, "")
```

Then drag the fill handles down to copy the formula into each of the cells in both columns.